# Check file accessibility .NET Core

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I would like to check if file is accessible.
I list file using

```
IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(_settings.appSettings.sourceDirectory);
var files = provider.GetDirectoryContents("");
```

Then i got a list of **IFileInfo** and **not FileInfo**

I would like to check if the file is not in use or in creation by a scanner or something like that (The program is a directory scanner (in the scanner reception folder) which send these files to a Web API)

In .NET 4.5 I could do this :

```
public static bool IsFileLocked(this FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But i can't do this in .NET Core 2 or 1

I can use the stream reader, but I need performance to read a maximum of files (this directory can get 1000 files every 30 seconds)

Thanks

Comment: Windows Compatibility pack installed? It adds back a lot of native functionality. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

Comment: @TomTom My soft need to work linux and windows..

This code could work

    bool IsFileOpen(string filePath)
{
  bool rtnvalue = false;
  try
  {
     System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath);
     fs.Close();
  }
  catch(System.IO.IOException ex)
  {
    rtnvalue = true;
  }
    return rtnvalue;
}

But this won't decrease performance ?

thanks

Comment: THen you rather make sure someone makes an API for that because checks are OS particular. Your example may reduce perforamnce, but it is the only way that works independent of the OS.

Comment: Thank you @TomTom

Comment: Note that the Windows Compatiblity Pack only works for Windows. If you use it, your program will no longer be cross-platform.

Comment: @omajid Ok thank you